# Remove prompt when leaving site (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Hey so I've been asked to fix an issue on this wordpress site (www.thetailife.com).

Whenever the user is trying to leave the page a prompt pops up asking them if they're sure they want to leave. I need to get rid of it so I've browsed this site and came across the code

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

but that doesn't help at all. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Update: It's been fixed!

Comment: just checked your site, it seems your site does not use window.onbeforeunload to make the prompt right now.

Comment: it seems your prompt problem is gone from the site now?

Comment: I just placed it in the footer.php that must have worked. May be taking a while to load the changes on the server because the prompt was still coming up in firefox. I'll close the question soon if it all checks out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting this at the very very end of your theme (footer)
so that this is the last js code... right before the end of  tag.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

a better solution is scan through your theme code / plugin and remove the actual code that was used to generate this prompt in the first place.